# Why do i keep getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_hash()?

Tags: php, sql

My code is :

```
function NewUser() 
{ 


    $fullname = $_POST['name'];
    $userName = $_POST['user'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];   
    $password = password_hash($_POST['pass']);
    $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);      

    #$password = stripslashes($password); 
    #$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

    $query = "INSERT INTO `WebsiteUsers`(`fullname`, `userName`, `email`, `pass`)   VALUES ('$fullname','$userName','$email','$password')"; 
    $data = mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error()); 


    if($data) 
    { 
    echo "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED..."; 
    } 
}
```

The error i keep getting is :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_hash()

Comment: `echo phpversion();` = ? <5.5 ?

Comment: The php version 5.3.20

Comment: You may not include the package file in the page where you call the function